# KDB/q Update table and insert

Tags: kdb

I want to put price qty and exchange_name but if the price already in the table i just want to update the quantity.
if the price is not in the table I want to insert it.
Is there a function to check if the price is already present, update it and if not insert it?
Else how do I check if price in the table .

`table:([]price:();qty:();exchange_name:())`

Comment: When you say update it, are you looking to add the qty if it already exists or just replace it? The latter could be achieved by keying the table by price and use `upsert` 
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/upsert/#keyed-table

Comment: How can i upsert by price in a simple table ?

Comment: Using keyed tables and upset is the out of the box solution. If you really insist on a non-keyed table I would probably key it and unkey it. `0!(1!table) upsert ([]price:1.5;qty:100;ex:`NASDAQ)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you key the table by `price` (or `price/exchange` if that is what you need) and upsert the fields that way? In code:

```
table:([] price:`float$(); qty:`int$(); exchange_name:`symbol$());

table:xkey[`price;table];
```

You can insert the rows as follow:

```
table:table upsert (20;200;`XPAR)
```

If you try to insert a row whose price is already shown in the table, `qty` and `exchange_name` will be updated; otherwise, a new row will be inserted.